# Cant concatinate a javascript variable inside an ajax which is inside another ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure how to ask this question but I'll just describe my problem:

I have this variable:

```
var htmlvalues = '';
```

then I have an ajax code:

```
#for loop here
$.ajax({
  url : 'dasdasdas',
  ...
  ....
  ....
  success : function (data) { 
    #now this is my problem here:
    $.ajax({
    url : 'dasdsa',
    ........
    .............
    success : function (data again) {
    htmlvalues += 'some html values to concatinate';
  }
  });
});
#end of for loop here
```

So after that loop ends I want to display that html values:

```
$(".tech-file-upload-dialog").html( htmlvalues );
```

In a dialog box like above. But it will just display an empty dialog box, I suspect It cant get those values inside the deeper part of ajax. I can see through console.log that my data are being concatinated successfully, it just can't reach the dialog box part.

Comment: in success you use "htmlvalues" and after loop you append "upload_success_html" value. both variable are same?

Comment: Sorry, its htmlvalues only

Comment: your solution is here: https://github.com/caolan/async but you have other problems

Answer (score 0):

Use **async:false**, so your code might look like.

```
var htmlvalues = '';

#for loop here
$.ajax({
async: "false",
  url : 'dasdasdas',
  ...
  ....
  ....
  success : function (data) { 
    #now this is my problem here:
    $.ajax({
    async: "false",
    url : 'dasdsa',
    ........
    .............
    success : function (data again) {
    htmlvalues += 'some html values to concatinate';
  }
  });
});
#end of for loop here

$(".tech-file-upload-dialog").html( htmlvalues );
```

Comment: can you explain how would that help?

Comment: in this code you might call example.php file via ajax and whatever data you get its display on dialog box, is it?

Comment: No, what is displayed is based on the values of the variable 'htmlvalues' which is just plain html JUST PLAIN HTML! nothing special

Comment: Means that "PLAIN HTML" display in dialog box or any element?

Comment: both plain html display

Answer (score -1):

Define your function as

```
...
success: function(data) {
  //do something
}
```

This way the function will get the response from the server parsed according to dataType you define in the call so you will have access to the data you need.

Comment: Could you please write more precise the code? You probably hide the outside data with the inner data by giving the same name...